# AssertionError when serialize Object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django I want to serialize (through Rest) a `Lecteur` object which looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Lecteur(User):
    bibliotheque = models.ManyToManyField('bibliotheque.Livre')
```

And the serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Lecteur
from bibliotheque.serializers import LivreSerializer

class LecteurSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bibliotheque = LivreSerializer(source='bibliotheque')
    class Meta:
        model=Lecteur
        fields = ('bibliotheque')
```

The problem is that I have a `AssertionError` when I evaluate this line
`serializer = LecteurSerializer(lecteur)` in my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def bibliotheque(request, id):
    """
    Show user's bibliotheque \w id    
    """
    try:
        lecteur = Lecteur.objects.get(id=id)
    except Lecteur.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = LecteurSerializer(lecteur)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, you should provide full traceback so we can dig into problem w/o recreating all your environment. It is common sense.

Here is the problem:

```
fields = ('bibliotheque')
```

As assertion error says, fields should be list or tuple, or other iterable.

Here you should undersntand one thing: Python tuple syntax conflicts with operations order syntax.
So, `('a') == 'a'`. To create a tuple of one element, you should use a hack: `('a',)`. Notice the comma!

So, if your case, fix will be:

```
fields = ('bibliotheque',)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work.

Here is the full traceback : http://pastebin.com/b1fD2SXS

Comment: @Totem so can you provide full traceback of your error?

Comment: I've edited my first comment, did you noticed the pastbinlink ?
If yes what can I add to give you complete insight of the project ?